# Need "Simple Menu" Twimlet guidance

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to create a simple alerting system using **Twimlets** but I'm either misunderstanding the way the Menu **Twimlet** should work or there's a bug.

Following "Example 1" from the "What is Simple Menu" page, when I invoke:

http://twimlets.com/menu?Message=Hi+There&Options[1]=http://foo.com

the following TwiML is returned:

```
<Response>
   <Gather numDigits="1">
      <Say>Hi There</Say>
   </Gather>
   <Redirect/>
</Response>
```

The thing that perplexes me is that there's no reference to the "http://foo.com" URL in the TwiML at all.

Am I doing something wrong or perhaps missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are doing anything wrong.
Basically what is going to happen, is that because no location was entered as you can see, when a user does press a digit, the result will be in a call back to the current document's url.

If you look through the source code snippet of the menu implementation here

```
// if DialStatus was sent, it means we got here after a Dial attempt
if (strlen($_REQUEST['Digits'])) 
{
    // if valid option given, the redirect
    if (strlen($location = $_REQUEST['Options'][$_REQUEST['Digits']])) 
    {
    header('Location: ' . $location);
    die;
} 
else 
{
    // answered call, so just hangup
    $response->say("I'm sorry, that wasn't a valid option.");
}
```

You will see that they are checking whether or not a digit is present and if so, they are extracting the location and then redirecting to that location.

the key part to this, will be understanding how the Twilio gather verb works, you find a better explanation here http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for responding to the oldish question.  It's still very much relevant so I'm quite happy to finally have an answer!

Comment: Pleasure Louis, glad I could help